# How does miner voting work?

Tags: mining-theory, governance, bip, voting

I always here people talk about miners being able to "vote" on certain things using the block chain. So here are my questions:

1) who gets to ask the questions?

2) what type of questions are being asked?

3) do they "vote" by selectively solving one block?

4) how is it even possible for even the biggest miners to **selectively** solve a block when the hash rate is so high?

5) does question #4 propose a vulnerability in the network?

Thanks. I never really understood this aspect of mining regarding big time mining farms

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'll try to answer your questions specifically, but [here's a good read on how Bitcoin votes on upgrades](https://www.cryptocompare.com/coins/guides/what-is-a-bips-bitcoin-improvement-proposal/).

1) The questions are really all the same question:  which [BIPs](https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/Bitcoin_Improvement_Proposals) do you support?  These proposals make their way through the Bitcoin development community, and once implemented, can be voted on by miners.  So basically, anyone can make a proposal.

2) See the answer to question 1

3) No

4) Since the answer to question 3 is "No", this question makes no sense.

5) See questions 3 and 4

EDIT:  I changed the link explaining BIP voting to one with less bias and opinion, and is much more concise an explanation.

Comment: Ahh, I see... Well that does answer my question about how it works, but I don't think that is the best way to go about voting in the Bitcoin community. It's like a weird mix of capitalism/free markets and democracy... Like I'm just imagining a nation where only Google and Facebook can vote on bills and policies in government, and I can't imagine a world where that would be a good place to live.

Comment: The problem you talk about is called "mining centralization", and it's something that worries a lot of people.  There was a recent question on this forum about what can be done about it.  You might find it interesting:  http://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/44543/what-can-be-done-to-slow-prevent-mining-centralization

Answer (score 0):

1) Typically developers put something for voting (via Bitcoin Improvement Proposals or BIPs).

2) Typically software development issues are being voted (new features, enhancements, testing, methodologies, etc.)

3,4,5) The voting usually resolves after N blocks, say 100 for example. Statistically, with 1% of the network's mining power you will have one vote (solved one block and voted). In a span of 100 blocks most major mining nodes would have a chance to vote. With 10% the node would have ~10 votes, etc. Again N could be lower/higher.